# Use Reports API to get report results as CSV

Tags: apex, csv, reports-api, convert

Using the Reports and Dashboards API is there a way to convert report results to CSV?

```
Reports.ReportResults results = Reports.ReportManager.runReport(reportId, true);
Map<String, Reports.ReportFact> fmap = results.getFactMap(); // how to convert to csv?
```

I am looking for an output that looks similar to the file that's generated when a report is exported as CSV. What I don't want is to manually parse the Fact Map as differentiating between summary-only and summary-detailed reports could be nasty.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [export to csv using analytics api](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/24808/is-there-a-way-to-export-a-report-using-analytics-api)

Comment: @SantanuHalder the post you're referring to is about the Analytics REST API whereas I am asking about the native Apex version of it -aka Reports and Dashboards API.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tabular report data via analytics API](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/49446/tabular-report-data-via-analytics-api)